# Use UPDATE statement in a CTE expression SQL

Tags: sql, algorithm, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have the following scenario:

I have tickets (=incidents) that have multiple activities.

An incident however can have a child ticket (+ grand child ticket) and so on:

[image]

That's why what I want to do, is to add all of the activities of the (grand)children, to the one of its parent.

So:

[image]

I began with retrieving all of the sub elements of a single ticket, I used a CTE for this:

```
With TicketTree(iID, pID)
as
(
    Select incidentID, parentID FROM incident where incidentID = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT incidentID, parentID FROM incident INNER JOIN TicketTree R on parentID = R.iID
)
Select  * from TicketTree
JOIN activity on TicketTree.iID = activity.incidentID
```

The query works and retrieves all of the sub incidents.

My question now is, is it possible to `UPDATE` the activity table and to set the `incidentID` of all the children to the one of the parent (using a query)?

I tried:

```
UPDATE activity
set incidentID = 1
WHERE incidentID IN(
Select  iID from TicketTree
JOIN activity on TicketTree.iID = activity.incidentID
)
```

It tells me that 11 rows were affected but the activities of the children did not change?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
With TicketTree(iID, pID) as (
      Select incidentID, parentID FROM incident where incidentID = 1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT incidentID, parentID FROM incident INNER JOIN TicketTree R on parentID = R.iID
     )
update activity
    set incidentID = 1
    where incidentID in (select iID in TicketTree);
```

Comment: but the problem is that i want to update the activity table (and not the incident table) :/